# Laravel and Cakephp not working on wamp

Tags: php, cakephp, laravel-4, wamp, wampserver

Can Laravel and Cakephp work on the same WAMP configuration? I have one running project in Cakephp but starting a new project in Laravel now.

I am having problems in configuring composer and having laravel up and running. Now, My localhost is completely messed up. So, before proceeding to fix the problem, I wanted to confirm if Cakephp and Laravel work simultaneously from same WAMP path?

Comment: wait a minute.Can 1000 php projects work on same localhost ? Yes ,so cakephp and laralevel are just php projects just a framework.Are they enemies of each other so one wont let other run and vice versa ?? :)

Comment: I followed the instructions from [link](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Laravel-Framework-in-Windows). Now, when I try to access the localhost/laravel/public/index.php, I get an error message saying "Failed to open stream", and localhost/laravel is "page cannot be displayed"

Comment: Does cakephp work well on localhost?

Comment: It used to till 30 mins ago. But now, after the configuration changes for laravel, my localhost is messed up

Comment: then revert all changes back.And Then do changes 1 by 1 . At same time check if cakephp works .When it stops working ,at that point THAT is WRONG configuration.

Comment: :-( in the process of reverting back everything... Let me see how that goes

Comment: @Pradeep Sure :) Tell  us if you get answer.

Comment: Setup a Virtual Host for each of your projects http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757

Comment: @Bogdan: Thanks for your suggestion. I reverted back all my changes and have cakphp up and running again. I am going to try Bogdan's suggestion of setting up virtual host for each of my projects. Will keep you guys posted.